# Filling HorizontalScrollView from right

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I programmatically add some text view to a linear layout starting from right, so put

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/results"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="12sp" 
        android:paddingRight="12sp" />
```

and coded

```
LinearLayout results= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.results);
TextView res = new TextView(this);
res.setId(resultsCounter );
res.setText(evaluated);
...............
results.addView(res);
```

and this works fine but I can't add indefinitely new items, so I added an horizontal scroll view

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollresults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35sp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="12sp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/results"
        ......
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

but filling LinearLayout I can scroll to right only, so I lost leftmost items